# slow search function google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a code i use to search for entries in a google sheet, the number of entries is 5000, it takes around 2 minutes for the search function to return a result, can you help shorten that time to reach the data am searching for, i provided the functions search records and get records.

```
function getRecords() { 
  var return_Array = [];
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); 
  var getLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  for(i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
    if(dataSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() != '')
    {
      return_Array.push([dataSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue(), 
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue(), 
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue(), 
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 10).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 12).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 13).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 14).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 15).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 16).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 17).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 18).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 19).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 20).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 21).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 22).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 23).getValue(),
      dataSheet.getRange(i, 24).getValue()]);
    }
  }  
  return return_Array;  
}*/
```

Comment: Can you provide the script of `getRecords()`?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i editted the post and added the code getrecords, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your updated question, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to `getValue()` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getRecords() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
  var return_Array = dataSheet.getRange("A2:X" + dataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([a]) => a);
  return return_Array;
}
```

- When this script is run, the rows of columns "A" to "X" where the value of column "A" is not empty are retrieved. And, in this case, I thought that the process cost can be reduced a little from your showing script.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)